# How to reliable query a Windows' system's "region"?

Tags: java

I am trying to adapt the date format in my Java application to the system's "Region" setting (at least that's what it is called in Windows' settings dialog).

I first tried doing this based on the `Locale` but `Locale.getDefault()` always gives me `en_US` albeit my system's region is set to `German (Switzerland)` and should thus yield `de_CH`.

According to some Google results this is a bug (apparently introduced with Java 7 which should have been fixed with Java 8 again, but obviously it is not - I am currently using Java 17). According to other results this is "as designed" and won't be fixed. Whatever it may be - it renders that method useless for my purpose.

Any idea, how one can query the system's *region* from Java?
As mentioned: this is for Java >= v17 and for Windows systems.

Comment: I think it is `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)`.

Comment: Indeed! This did the trick! Thanks. Please post that as response, so I can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to use `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)` to get the regional formatting config from Windows. It looks like `getDefault()` reports the display language (though I'm only guessing based on observed behaviour).

For example, on my machine (Windows 11), my Windows display language is set to "English (United States)", `Locale.getDefault()` returns `en_US`.

My regional settings are set to Country or region: Netherlands, and Regional format to "Recommended" (the expanded details show it as "English (Netherlands)"). `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)` reports `en_NL`.

If I change the Regional format to "Dutch (Netherlands)", `getDefault()` still reports `en_US`, but `getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)` reports `nl_NL`.